# What is the best practice to use parentCtrl method in ChildCtrl with controller as syntax？

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, q

As the code shows,I want to use the parentCtrl add method in ChildCtrl because I want to notice the parentCtrl to refresh when it's done.

Do I have to use $emit or something?(I've think about it,but I would like to use add method in the parentCtrl context).

This is the way I use now,it works but I find it weird,what is the best way to do that?

```
function myserve() {
    var self = this;
    self.saveDefer = function (defer) {
        self.defer = defer
    }
    self.getDefer = function () {
        return self.defer
}}

function parentCtrl($q) {
    self.workers = ['tom', 'jack'];
    self.add = function (worker) {
        add(workder).then(refresh) 
    }
    self.clickGoChild = function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        defer.promise.then(self.add);
        myserve.saveDefer(defer);
        $state.go('child');
    }

function childCtrl() {
    self.doAdd = function () {
    myserve.getDefer().resolve(self.newWorker)
}}
// I want to use add method in parentCtrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the scopes are prototypical inherited, there is no real inheritance in ngController.

It is possible to define the "add" method in the service so both controllers can use it independently. Then in order to refresh the "parent controller" just send an event like "controllerA:refresh" when you done adding.